# Why there is no diffraction in the microwave oven's door?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, interference, diffraction, microwaves

I thought that hole smaller than wavelength causes strong diffraction.
[image: slit diffraction]

Holes in door of the microwave oven 100 times smaller than wavelength. Why does it block radiation?

[image: microwave oven's door]

Comment: This is the best answer to the question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141562/diffraction-by-small-holes