# I’m unable to prove why maximum diffraction when wavelength = aperture size

Tags: visible-light, diffraction

*I know this is a popular topic, but I haven't read a similar argument to mine below, so here goes:*

The phase difference between the top and the bottom of a slit of width $$,
for waves emerging at an angle $\theta$,
is $\phi$

Following the usual phasor construction to derive the result:
$I=I_0sinc{\frac{\phi}{2}}$

whose minima occur when $\phi = 2n\pi$
therefore

$\sin{\theta}=\frac{n\lambda}{a}$

With the construction shown here:
[image: Phasor construction for single slit]

---

Considering the familiar statement:

*diffraction is at a maximum when slit width = wavelength*

I would say the following

As $0\leq\theta<90$ by definition, then for a certain order beam
$\theta\sim\arcsin{\frac{\lambda}{a}}$

1. For $\lambda=a , \theta$ is maximised, as expected
2. For $\lambda < a , \theta \rightarrow 0$, also as expected

**but my question is: how do we account for $\lambda > a$, since arcsin is undefined for arguments outside $[-1,1]$?**

I hope my questions has been laid out clearly - it's taken quite a while to write this out :) Thanks.

Comment: No zero of intensity occurs?

Comment: *diffraction is at a maximum when slit width = wavelength* You say this is a "familiar statement," but I've never heard of it. By "diffraction is at a maximum," do you mean that the diffraction pattern is as broad as possible? By what measure? Could you give us a source for this claim? In the limit $a\ll \lambda$, the transmission is $(a/\lambda)^4$, and the radiation approaches a dipole pattern. So in this limit I'd expect the angular distribution to approach a constant. Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141562/diffraction-by-small-holes/141713

Comment: @BenCrowell I can't give a proper source atm; I've just known about it ever since my A Level days. I just found it in this BBC article too: https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/z99kkqt/revision/3 third paragraph down. I happened to be revisiting some wave physics, and realised I didn't know **why** this should be the case.